# ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer returns an invalid parameter error

Tags: c++, directx-11

I wrote this function in order to do all the necessary steps to create a constant buffer in one function call.

```
template <typename T> 
ID3D11Buffer* Engine::CreateCBuffer(T &src,ENGINE_DATA &data, int registerV)
{
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;

ZeroMemory(&bd, sizeof(bd));
bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(T);
bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
bd.StructureByteStride = 0;
bd.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
bd.MiscFlags = 0;


// Fill in the subresource data.        
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA subrsrc;         
subrsrc.pSysMem = &src;                 
subrsrc.SysMemPitch = 0;                
subrsrc.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;                                                               

ID3D11Buffer* pBuffer;

data.device->CreateBuffer(&bd, &subrsrc, &pBuffer);
data.devContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(registerV, 1, &pBuffer);

return pBuffer;
}
```

I've already used it to pass the trnsformation/view/projection matrices to the vertex buffer.
Now I'm trying to pass a light position in another constant buffer.

```
//code for matrices buffer
renderer.getObject(0)->setTMBuffer(
        CeateCBuffer(renderer.getObject(0)->getTransformationMatrix()->transformationMatrix, data, 1));


//code for light position buffer
lBuffer = CreateCBuffer(light.direction, data, 0);
```

In both cases all the variables are correctly declared and initialized.

That's the shader code part relative to these buffers.

```
cbuffer LIGHT : register (b0)
{
    float3 light_direction;

};

cbuffer TRANSFORMATION_MATRIX : register (b1)
{
    float4x4 transformationMatrix;
};
```

I don't understand why the function CreateBuffer returns error 87 (invalid parameter) when i try to create the light position buffer.

Comment: Where are you checking the error? You don't check the return value of CreateBuffer and GetLastError (@err in the debugger) has nothing to do with this code.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. In order to help you with your problem we need a [mcve].

Comment: I omitted the error checking part because it was not in the original code I wrote. I use HRESULT_CODE to get the error code

Comment: I cannot make this code complete if you need it to be minimal, which part of it isn't clear enough?

Comment: What is the type of `renderer.getObject(0)->getTransformationMatrix()->transformationMatrix`? note that `bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(T);` must be multiple of 16 bytes,

Comment: The type of renderer.getObject(0)->getTransformationMatrix()->transforma‌​tionMatrix is XMFLOAT4X4. if bd.ByteWidth is not multiple of 16 bytes what would happen?

Comment: Then `CreateBuffer` would fail.

Comment: So I have to use a XMFLOAT4 instead and also change the float3 to float4 in the shader?

Comment: You can use float3 in the shader. But the size of the buffer still needs top be multiple of 16 bytes. That is you need to add 4 bytes of padding when copying which will probably require to copy float3 into temporary buffer. Actually just using XMFLOAT4 for buffer (without changing shader) would be more convenient.